# Have an array of people and need to drop the persons age if they are over 2 with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

My array is lool like this below code:

`var gillFamily = [{name: 'john', age: 20}, {name: 'richard', age: 27}, {name: 'debbie', age: 55}, {name: 'dan', age 25}, {name: 'robin', age 60}]`

And if the family member is over 26. Drop their age.

Example:

`[{name: 'john', age: 20}, {name: 'richard'}]`

I have done with below mentioned code, but it didn't work for me.

`.chain(gillFamily)
.dropWhile(gillFamily, function(over) { return over.age > 26; })
.map(function (over) { return over.name; })
.value()`

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Comment: what exactly you mean by `drop`

Comment: as in say that person doesnt want their name displayed if it is over 26. so it would only show the name not their age when you dsplay the array

Answer (score 1):

You can use array map function

```
var gillFamily = [{
  name: 'john',
  age: 20
}, {
  name: 'richard',
  age: 27
}, {
  name: 'debbie',
  age: 55
}, {
  name: 'dan',
  age: 25
}, {
  name: 'robin',
  age: 60
}]
```

**JS**

```
// using map function
var m = gillFamily.map(function(a) {
  // check if 20 is less than age of the person
  // if so then delete the age key
  20 < a.age && delete a.age;
  return a // return the object
});
console.log(m);
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/94bbn7y7/)

Comment: Note that this code modifies the objects in the original `gillFamily` array.

Answer (score 1):

use `_.omit` to remove key from object

```
var res = _.map(gillFamily, function(over) {
    return over.age > 26 ? _.omit(over, 'age') : over;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with lodash

```
const result = _.filter(gillFamily, function (item) {
      item.age > 20 && delete item.age;
      return item;
})
```